# GitHub pull request unresolved comments

Tags: github, pull-request

I have a questions regarding GitHub pull requests. Is there a way in GitHub, not to push to the branches if there are unresolved comments? Also, is there a way, when the PR is closed, the same branch not to make any push? Thank you in advance.

Greetings,

Felipe

Comment: I assume you mean automatic ways. Manually: just make the branch protected and have nobody with rights to push to it.

Answer (score 0):

Disallowing pushes to a branch where the pull request has unresolved conversations would be counterproductive; many issues are resolved by adding (or amending) commits to fix the raised issue. But if you mean you want to disallow merges of that branch (either in GitHub itself or by pushing a merged branch), this can be done via branch protection rules.

In the repository's settings, you have to set up a corresponding branch protection rule for all of your branches that receive merges (i.e. `master` and maybe other long-lived branches).

Code and automation > Branches > ☑ Require conversation resolution before merging

[image: GitHub settings screenshot]